# ListView doesn't hit ItemInserting event

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have the following ListView that should raise an ItemInserting event, but as I step through the process, it never hits this event. Any clues? All the FindChild controls are found and values returned. I have searched for hours upon hours and don't understand why it's not working. Using ASP.Net 4.0.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcSiteInvite" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csRemote %>"
    SelectCommand="spSiteInvite" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Friends(RequestSenderUserID, FriendFirstName, FriendLastName, FriendEmail) VALUES ( @User , @FirstName, @LastName, @Email)"
    runat="server">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="User" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:ListView ID="lsvSiteInvite" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" DataSourceID="srcSiteInvite" OnItemInserting="lsvSiteInvite_ItemInserting" runat="server">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Enter Friend Information</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFriendFirstName" Text="<b>First Name:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFriendFirstName" Text='<%# Bind("FriendFirstName") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFriendFirstName" ControlToValidate="txtFriendFirstName"
                ErrorMessage="Friend first name is required." runat="server"><span style="font-weight:bold; color:Red;">*</span>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFriendLastName" Text="<b>Last Name:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFriendLastName" Text='<%# Bind("FriendLastName") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFriendLastName" ControlToValidate="txtFriendLastName" 
                ErrorMessage="Friend last name is required." runat="server"><span style="font-weight:bold; color:Red;">*</span>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFriendEmail" Text="<b>E-mail:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFriendEmail" Text='<%# Bind("FriendEmail") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFriendEmail" ControlToValidate="txtFriendEmail" 
                ErrorMessage="Friend e-mail is required." runat="server"><span style="font-weight:bold; color:Red;">*</span>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFriendEmail" ControlToValidate="txtFriendEmail"
                ErrorMessage="E-mail is not in proper format." ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnFriendSubmit" CommandArgument="Insert" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnFriendCancel" CommandArgument="Cancel" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnFriendCancel_Click" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
...
</asp:ListView>


protected void lsvSiteInvite_ItemInserting(Object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = Helpers.FindChild(this, "txtFriendFirstName") as TextBox;
    e.Values["FirstName"]=txt.Text;
    txt = Helpers.FindChild(this, "txtFriendLastName") as TextBox;
    e.Values["LastName"] = txt.Text;
    txt = Helpers.FindChild(this, "txtFriendEmail") as TextBox;
    e.Values["Email"] = txt.Text;
    e.Values["User"] = UserInformation.UserID;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `OnItemInserting="lsvSiteInvite_ItemInserting"` to your listview markup. This will bind the method to the `OnItemInserting` event:

**EDIT 2 :** You need to pass CommandName to the ListView. **Change this line**:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnFriendSubmit" CommandArgument="Insert" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

**To this**:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFriendSubmit" CommandName ="Insert" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

**EDIT :** In your markup you have a button with "Insert" command. Looks like you are expecting to trigger the ListView's OnItemInserting event. To use the button, you have to add `OnItemCommand="lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand"` to your listview markup and in the code `lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand` method will be called:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lsvSiteInvite" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" 
DataSourceID="srcSiteInvite" OnItemCommand="lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand" runat="server">
```

**EDIT 3 :**  I have used the following code and markup to test your code. You can download my test project and DbScript [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0OWRIOUFMTFhONW8/edit?usp=sharing).

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ListViewTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcSiteInvite" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csRemote %>"
    SelectCommand="spSiteInvite" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Friends(RequestSenderUserID, FriendFirstName, FriendLastName, FriendEmail) VALUES ( @User , @FirstName, @LastName, @Email)"
    runat="server">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="User" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:ListView ID="lsvSiteInvite" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" 
DataSourceID="srcSiteInvite" OnItemCommand="lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand" runat="server">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Enter Friend Information</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFriendFirstName" Text="<b>First Name:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFriendFirstName" Text='<%# Bind("FriendFirstName") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFriendFirstName" ControlToValidate="txtFriendFirstName"
                ErrorMessage="Friend first name is required." runat="server"><span style="font-weight:bold; color:Red;">*</span>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFriendLastName" Text="<b>Last Name:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFriendLastName" Text='<%# Bind("FriendLastName") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFriendLastName" ControlToValidate="txtFriendLastName" 
                ErrorMessage="Friend last name is required." runat="server"><span style="font-weight:bold; color:Red;">*</span>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFriendEmail" Text="<b>E-mail:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFriendEmail" Text='<%# Bind("FriendEmail") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFriendEmail" ControlToValidate="txtFriendEmail" 
                ErrorMessage="Friend e-mail is required." runat="server"><span style="font-weight:bold; color:Red;">*</span>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFriendEmail" ControlToValidate="txtFriendEmail"
                ErrorMessage="E-mail is not in proper format." ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnFriendSubmit" CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnFriendCancel" CommandArgument="Cancel" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnFriendCancel_Click" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr><td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="<b>First Name:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" /></td><td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFriendFirstName" Text='<%# Bind("FriendFirstName") %>' Width="85px" runat="server" /><br /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="<b>Last Name:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" /></td><td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFriendLastName" Text='<%# Bind("FriendLastName") %>' Width="85px" runat="server" /><br /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text="<b>E-mail:</b>" Width="85px" runat="server" /></td><td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFriendEmail" Text='<%# Bind("FriendEmail") %>' Width="85px" runat="server" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm1.ascx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ListViewTest
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
            {
                ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)e.Item;
                var firstName = item.FindControl("txtFriendFirstName") as TextBox;
                var lastName = item.FindControl("txtFriendLastName") as TextBox;
                var email = item.FindControl("txtFriendEmail") as TextBox;
                var user = "1";// UserInformation.UserID;//Test code

                if (firstName != null && lastName != null && email != null)
                {
                    //Your code to insert
                    srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["User"].DefaultValue = user;
                    srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = firstName.Text.ToString();
                    srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = lastName.Text.ToString();
                    srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = email.Text.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void btnFriendCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output I got from test:
[image]

Comment: You're right, I omitted that reference this last time around upon experimenting in desperation. Added it back in with the same unsuccessful results. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @muybn - It is not clear to me how you are inserting item in ListView. Also, you have validators in page., try disabling them.

Comment: Very strange that ItemCommand wasn't mentioned in any other sources I've been perusing the last couple of days. Unfortunately, the program just stepped over the instructions after the "if (e.CommandName == "Insert")" line (the CommandName was "").

Comment: @muybn - Please see Edit 2.

Comment: The Cancel button is working just the way I like it. I need to insert records into the database. The fact that while stepping through, the program doesn't hit the ItemInserting event nor the if (e.CommandName == "Insert")... leads me to conclude that it isn't "considering" the Insert command on the button as an Insert command at all. Very perplexing.

Comment: @muybn - you have to add `CommandName ="Insert"` in btnFriendSubmit to work as expected. I already have updated the answer in Edit 2. Please try again and let me know.

Comment: @muybn - CommandName. You can download the test project to compare with your code. I have edited my answer with fully tested code and link to test project.

Comment: You're wonderful for sticking with me. If you lived nearby, I'd take you to dinner. OK, now the if CommandName="Insert" section is catching in the code; not sure why it wasn't before.

I am getting this error...

Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem'.

on this line:

ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

Not sure why I'm getting it and you didn't.

Comment: I know... If you check the updated answer, it is ListViewItem, not ListViewDataItem. Silly mistake from my side. So, please replace ListViewDataItem  with ListViewItem and test again.

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much, Afzalulh! I had to change the way I retrieved UserID and had to add ".ToString()" to "= UserID". Will try to show in an edit above; can't do it here. The absolutely disconcerting thing is that in the literally dozens of online articles I consulted, including those written by Microsoft themselves, all emphasized the ItemInserting method. As far as I remember, none of them explained anything close to what you did.

Comment: See final code at end of this page. I don't know if I have enough points, whatever, to accept or upvote. I've tried that before in other posts and had problems doing so, but I'll do what I can. They have some strange rules on this site. Any ideas why "OnItemInserting" didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This was what worked:

```
protected void lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)e.Item;
        var firstName = item.FindControl("txtFriendFirstName") as TextBox;
        var lastName = item.FindControl("txtFriendLastName") as TextBox;
        var email = item.FindControl("txtFriendEmail") as TextBox;
        var userInfoList = UserInfo.UserInfoGetByUserID(UserID);
        UserInformation = userInfoList.FirstOrDefault();
        var user = UserInformation.UserID;
        if (firstName != null && lastName != null && email != null)
        {
            //Your code to insert
            srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["User"].DefaultValue = user.ToString();
            srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = firstName.Text.ToString();
            srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = lastName.Text.ToString();
            srcSiteInvite.InsertParameters["Email"].DefaultValue = email.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Insert an Item You have to fire OnItemInserting event of listview. for this just o to properties of listview and double click on OnItemInserting go to code file and write your insert code in this method
 just like html is

```
<asp:ListView ID="lsvSiteInvite" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnItemInserting="lsvSiteInvite_ItemInserting" DataSourceID="srcSiteInvite" runat="server">
```

and in code file

```
protected void lsvSiteInvite_ItemInserting(Object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
TextBox txt = Helpers.FindChild(this, "txtFriendFirstName") as TextBox;
e.Values["FirstName"]=txt.Text;
txt = Helpers.FindChild(this, "txtFriendLastName") as TextBox;
e.Values["LastName"] = txt.Text;
txt = Helpers.FindChild(this, "txtFriendEmail") as TextBox;
e.Values["Email"] = txt.Text;
e.Values["User"] = UserInformation.UserID;
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.iteminserting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the item inserting event of listview This event only fire. if a control having command name Insert is clicked

Comment: Thank you, I added reference to the ItemInserting event back in, to no avail. Still the same unsuccessful results.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about why ItemInserting didn't work in this case?